# Tkinter no display error

Tags: python-3, pi-4, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter and running into the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "TKtest.py", line 3, in <module>
    master = tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

My code is as simple as it gets:

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
```

Note: I am *not* using SSH. This is just my Pi 4 connected via HDMI to the 7 inch touchscreen.
Note2: I already tried to set DISPLAY:0.0 but this doesn't solve the problem: echo $DISPLAY also gives :0.0

How do I solve this error?

Comment: Are you running it on the desktop? What happens if you run `DISPLAY=:0 ~/TKtest.pi` ?

Comment: Permission denied, tried multiple files

Comment: OK Try `DISPLAY=:0 python3 ~/TKtest.py`

Comment: Tried that, as well as
sudo DISPLAY=:0 python3 /TKtest.py (need acces to GPIO)
This returns me with: couldn't connect to display ":0"

Comment: @Dougie Thanks a lot! Your solution worked on my Linux Mint LMDE 4, using: Tkinter 8.6 and crontab